# How do I transfer Chrome extensions to another 'Person'?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm just wondering how I can transfer my Chrome extensions from one signed in user, to a separate 'Person'? i.e. Person 1.

Answer (score 5):

Extensions are stored in that person's Chrome profile, which can be found at %userprofile%\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data. Extensions are contained in seperate folders within the Default directory. Transferring the extension is as simple as copying or moving the folder from the original user's folder to the target user's folder. I know this can be done because I have done it before and currently sync my Chrome extensions and bookmarks across a domain by using a batch file to sync the files and it works flawlessly. These same principles apply to your history, settings, bookmarks, etc... most of your Chrome data is stored in this folder.

Your extensions will typically be in a folder with many letters and numbers in the folder name. That is the unique ID of the extension.

Hope this works for you,

Comment: For Macs, the profile data is stored in `Users/jesse_new/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`. But matching a profile folder to a profile name isn't straight-forward. For me, my "Guest" profile is in the `Default` folder and the profile for my Google account is in the `Person 1` folder. You can find the exact folder for the current profile by opening chrome://version and look for the "Profile Path" value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pack the extension first from Extensions settings. Just select "Pack Extension" button and select the folder inside hex code folder(folder with many letters and numbers) because it has a manifest.json file. After it's done, it will create two files ".crx" and ".pem". Just drag and drop the .crx file on the Extensions page and it should install that extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed an extension for Person 1 via the Chrome Web Store, it's best to simply install it again for Person 2 by opening a browser window under Person 2 and searching for the extension in Chrome Web Store.

This way you will not cause any errors or weird behavior which may result from following other answers. They are still good if you are dealing with a sideloaded extension or you have a lot of persona or extensions to transfer.

Comment: I'm really not happy that each profile is taking close to 100MB... (i'm storing it in a ramdisk) it would be nice if chrome would share extensions between profiles.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me. Here's what did, and proved to be the easiest/fastest way to get all extensions from one profile onto another.

1. In Chrome, go to https://chromewebstore.google.com/user/installed
2. Ctrl(Cmd on Mac)+Click each extension listed to open its Chrome web store page in a new tab
3. Once the pages are open for all of your extensions, Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+D (or in Chrome **menu > bookmarks > bookmark all tabs**), and name the folder **Extensions**
4. go to **menu > bookmarks > show all bookmarks**, or open the **bookmark manager**
5. navigate to whichever location the **Extensions** folder was saved in
6. sign into your other profile (opens a new chrome window for it)
7. drag and drop the **Extensions** folder onto the bookmarks bar
8. right-click the **Extensions** folder on the bookmarks bar in the window for the new profile, and select **Open all (n) in new window**
9. go through each page and click to add the extension to chrome for your new profile